# Changing $before_widget for certain widgets

Tags: themes, widgets, sidebar

So I'm working on designing a Wordpress theme with lots of extra widgets. The ones I have added are in separate files, and called in the functions.php I have lots of css on the widgets themselves and the div classes are in the $before_widget and $after_widget etc in functions.php. My problem is that for certain widgets I don't want the same CSS, for example no background or border. I can't seem to work out how to go about this. If that makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to allow separate styles on each widget. The first is to add separate classes to the widgets like this:

### First Method

```
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'sidebar1',
 'before_widget' => '<ul class="black-bg"><li>',
 'after_widget' => "</li></ul>",
 'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
 'after_title' => "</h2>"
  ));
```

You can then use the .back-bg class to style the widget like this:

```
#sidebar .black-bg {
background:black;
}
```

and with no border:

```
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'sidebar2',
 'before_widget' => '<ul class="no-border"><li>',
 'after_widget' => "</li></ul>",
 'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
 'after_title' => "</h2>"
  ));
```

the css would be for instance:

```
#sidebar .no-border {
border:none;
}
```

### The Second Method

You could also use the theme file where you're placing the call to the sidebar/widget. For this way you would just use the same before and after widget, but use a class or id to wrap the sidebar in the template file like this:

```
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'sidebar1',
 'before_widget' => '<ul><li>',
 'after_widget' => "</li></ul>",
 'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
 'after_title' => "</h2>"
  ));
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'sidebar2',
 'before_widget' => '<ul><li>',
 'after_widget' => "</li></ul>",
 'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
 'after_title' => "</h2>"
  ));
```

Then in whatever-themefile.php you could do this:

```
  <div class="black-bg">
    <?php if ( function_exists ( dynamic_sidebar(1) ) ) : ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar (1); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
```

The style:

```
.black-bg {
background:black;
}
```

And...

```
  <div class="no-border">
    <?php if ( function_exists ( dynamic_sidebar(2) ) ) : ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar (2); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>


.no-border {
border:none;
}
```

### Response to Comment:

I just assumed you meant sidebar. Most refer to custom sidebars as "widgets", so let me try again.

I don't completely picture what you're wanting, but each custom widget you register will have it's own class. If the widget is used more than once, it just seems to make sense to me to use the "location" it will be placed to handle the styling (which would be the dynamic_sidebar it's place in).

If you're talking about how to add separate style to a single widget that is placed more than once in a given sidebar I would simply use the css pseudo selectors (odd/even). For example:

```
/*EVEN*/
#sidebar .black-bg:nth-child(even) {
background:transparent;
border:none;
}

/*ODD*/
#sidebar .black-bg:nth-child(odd) {
background: black;
border:1px dotted silver;
}
```

Comment: Way to out do me on the explanation :)

Comment: I must have been seconds behind you. I was clicking the submit button as it displayed the possible answer message :}

Comment: Okay thank you both for your answers. But doesn't what you explained register a second sidebar, by having register_sidebar twice? Cause the idea is to style the widget and only that widget, then the user can put it anywhere in the sidebar and it keeps its style...

Comment: See my revised answer. If that doesn't cover it please respond with the exact scenario you're talking about.

Comment: I'm not worried about styling the same widget more than once. I'm trying to -simply- style a given widget individually, where it is placed in a sidebar isn't the issue. I could have two separate sidebars and I could style the $before_widget differently and that would work, but that's what I'm trying to avoid. I want to just have one sidebar but change the $before_widget (removing the background and border) for one given widget. E.G the search bar, or Twitter follower counter.. if this makes more sense.

Comment: I'll sleep and re-read your comment. I think we're miscommunicating. As I see it you can style the "sidebars" which contain the "widgets". Or you can style the widgets which reside in the sidebars. Each can be styled individually from each-other and from the other widgets/sidebars. The before/after allows the widget styles. The div id="whatever-widget-containing-sidebar" can be used to style the widget containing sidebar. In my first example 2 s-bars are registered, but they both would go in the sidebar.php and would appear as one s-bar.

Comment: Okay, I understand completely what you are saying, however I'm trying style individual widgets in ONE sidebar.. yes everything in a single sidebar is styled by before/after widget. But I'm trying to overide that for certain widgets, like the search widget.. it doesn't need a box, yet because it's under that sidebar style it gets one. So for that widget I'm trying to give it a different class, without making a new sidebar.

Comment: The simple way would be to add an additional sidebar. The alternative would be to either hook into the WordPress default search widget or add some jQuery to add an id to it. You could also unregister the sear-widget and add your own. This link shows how: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28163/removing-the-default-sidebar-from-admin-panel but I'd just use firebug to see what the id of the element is. The search widget can be styled using .widget_search{
background:black;
}.

Comment: OMG! I solved it!! Simple answer. In the widget files that I created. I removed the echo $before_widget; and after widget! I totally forgot they were there for the custom widget files. Now I'll add my own div class for them and I'm sorted! Thanks so much for the help. Appreciate it!

Comment: Yeah, no echo's in my example codes. I was starting to wonder about you :)

Answer (score 0):

That's what `$before_widget` is all about. You would do `array('before_widget' => '<span class="some-class".',after_widget' => '</span>)` then style `.some-class` to whatever you want. You can have more than one class or even style it by the widgets ID. If this isn't what you're asking please clarify the question.